# Deploy to Maven Packages via GitHub Actions

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

So, I have a GitHub Repository with compiled Maven projects. I setup a GitHub Actions to deploy them to GitHub Packages. This is my current release-package.yml:

```yaml
name: Maven Package

on: push

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
      - uses: actions/setup.java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
          server-id: github
          server-username: ...
          server-password: ...
      - name: Publish Package
        run: |
          chmod +x ./deploy.sh
          ./deploy.sh
        shell: bash
```

As one can see, 'server-username' and 'server-password' are still blank, which is my main problem. I read here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-java-packages-with-maven that I have to add this but I don't know what username and password to use except my own. But I want to avoid that.
The deploy.sh has the following content:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

OWNER=...
REPOSITORY=...

filelist=$(find . -type f -path "*.pom")
for file in $filelist
do
    data=$(python getdata.py $file)
    groupId=$(echo $data | cut -d' ' -f1)
    artifactId=$(echo $data | cut -d' ' -f2)
    version=$(echo $data | cut -d' ' -f3)

    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=$groupId -DartifactId=$artifactId -Dversion=$version -Dfile=$file -Durl=https://maven.pkg.github.com/$OWNER/$REPOSITORY
done
```

In this case 'OWNER' and 'REPOSITORY' are purposely empty.

I already tried to use Actions secrets or Deploy keys but I don't really understand them and the documentation is not really explaining anything. When I tried these solution it failed with an 401 Unauthorized error code.

The question is which credentials do I have to use? The documentation confuses me and I don't know if my approach is optimal. It would be really nice if someone could help me. Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE

New workflow I tried:

```yaml
name: Maven Package

on: push

jobs:
  publish-gpr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      deployments: write
      packages: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: '3.10'
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Publish Package
        run: |
          chmod +x ./deploy.sh
          ./deploy.sh
        shell: bash
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

And this is the error I always get:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact <artifact> from/to remote-repository (https://maven.pkg.github.com/<repo-path>): authentication failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/<repo-path>/<path-to-jar>, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct term is "publish" here, not "deploy".

`actions/setup.java` should be [`actions/setup-java`](https://github.com/actions/setup-java) i.e. replace `.` with `-`.

You need to follow [Publishing packages to GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-java-packages-with-maven#publishing-packages-to-github-packages).

Regarding `server-username` and `server-password`, you don't have to configure these for GitHub Packages as they already have the correct defaults i.e. `GITHUB_ACTOR` and `GITHUB_TOKEN` respectively, see [Maven options](https://github.com/actions/setup-java#maven-options).

Refer to the [`github`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) context to configure `OWNER` and `REPOSITORY` values.

Comment: I did what you told me to do. I removed the server-... from the file and added `env: GITHUB_TOKEN` as the docs you gave me said. But it still fails and returns the error code 401. Is it possible that maven does not use the correct credentials?

Comment: @MagaCraft202: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76275911/edit) your question add your workflow that you just tried under an **UPDATE** section.

Comment: Yeah sure, I forgot that. Sorry

Comment: @MagaCraft202: Have you verified if the URL has the correct value?

Comment: yes, I have. This is the URL I'm using: `https://maven.pkg.github.com/<username>/<repository>/<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>/<jar>`

Comment: @MagaCraft202: Does your `pom.xml` have `distributionManagement` and its nested `repository` configured for `github` as in the docs? I just tested a sample project and specifiied the required arguments for [deploy-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) and it worked fine. See my [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5013948667/workflow), successful [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/5013948667/jobs/8987640936), and the published [package](https://github.com/iamazeem?ecosystem=maven&tab=packages).

Comment: yes, but I had to add -DpomFile=$file as an argument because it got the wrong pom file. It works now and thank you for your help! :)